# Get Application Name while loading Spring @Configuration file

Tags: java, spring, configuration, spring-annotations

I am using `Spring Framework 4`. I have common project like **TestApplication** which is Aspect based and pull logs on applications **App1** and **App2**.

I am using `@Configuration` completely annotation based configuration in **TestApplication**.

**App1** and **App2** have separate spring Configuration and hence separate contexts and loads **TestApplication** individually.

**Question:**
while **App1** is loaded, **TestApplication**'s `@Configuration` gets loaded and within that file i need to get application name as `App1`.
Similarly when **App2** is loaded, within `@Configuration` file of **TestApplication** I need to get application name as `App2`.

I tried using `ApplicationContext`'s `getApplicationName()` method and works well locally. But in DEV/PROD regions might be using DNS and hence not applicable.

Suggestions please.

**edited:**
One approach identified is to update `web.xml` of application with `context-param` and `value` and access it via `@Value(value="${context-param-name}")` annotation. Works fine but requires `property place holder` to be configured in `spring xml`.

Comment: you can simple distinguish environment based upon URL, can 't you think so ?

Comment: @vishalgajera I need the application name value during bean initialization. Based upon that I need to pull certain values from DB. these values will vary for App1 and App2. I need application name to be unique across all environements.